# Disable Subject Alternative Names (SAN) verification on self-signed certificates

Tags: java, rest, ssl, jboss, wildfly

I have a WildFly instance (let us call it **Instance 1**) with a self-signed certificate added to the keystore. That certificate was created using **KeyStore Explorer 5.2.1**.

The generated certificate only has CN specified which is the name of the server\hostname where **Instance 1** is installed. I didn’t specify any SANs, because I want the applications installed on Instance 1 to be accessible locally (either through "127.0.0.1" or "localhost") or remotely (either by hostname or LAN IP).

There is only one application (let us call it **Application A**) installed on **Instance 1**, which provided several REST Web Services

I have another WildFly instance (let us call it **Instance 2**) in another server. Using **KeyStore Explorer 5.2.1** I imported the previously generated certificate to the truststore of that instance.

**Instance 2** only has 1 application (let us call it **Application B**) that accesses the REST Web Services provided by the **Application A**

If **Application B** specifies the IP instead of the hostname of the server where **Application A** is installed I get the following exception:

- ***javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present***

I don’t want to specify the IP on the SAN certificate, because if the IP of the server where **Instance 1** is installed changed the certificate will become invalid in cases where the REST services are called using LAN IP.

From what I’ve seen, a possible solution is to set the following properties:

```
<property name="org.jboss.security.ignoreHttpsHost" value="true"/>
<property name="cxf.tls-client.disableCNCheck" value="true"/>
```

None of them worked.

Any help on this matter would be appreciated.